# Finding out the NSTextField for a field editor

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, fieldeditor

I' using

```
- (id)windowWillReturnFieldEditor:(NSWindow *)sender toObject:(id)anObject
```

to provide my own field editor so i can display a custom context menu.
This works but when inside the "menuForEvent:" method of my field editor, how can i find to which NSTextField it is attached?

EDIT: okay i found that i get it via inside the TextView via

```
[[[[self window] firstResponder] nextResponder] nextResponder]
```

The question is - is this a good solution or a hack.
I have to skip an internal responder of class _NSKeyboardFocusClipView so i scared that this might not work on future Cocoa versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't want to rely on the responder chain for that, seems rather fragile.

I'd try to add a property to my field editor class and set that to anObject in the `windowWillReturnFieldEditor:toObject:` delegate method.

Comment: I tried this before but it doesn't work for some nknown reasons. BTW putting a printf in this method made me sick to see how many times it is called.

Comment: This is a great approach, just beware of retain cycles between the text field and the field editor (text view). By the way, another suitable spot to set the reference is in `fieldEditor(for:)` in a custom subclass of `NSTextFieldCell`.